# How can I set bitstream vera sans mono font in win7 cmd?

Tags: r, windows-7, fonts, console

I set bitstream vera sans mono font in R on win7, please see the attachment.

[image]

How can I set bitstream vera sans mono font in CMD on win7? Please see my font in cmd on win7, from the word "link", you will know it is not the bitstream vera sans mono font.

[image]

I have set

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\currentVersion\console\TrueTypeFont
```

into  bitstream vera sans mono, it doesn't work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to share how I managed to setup the `Bitstream Vera Sans Mono`, the fixed-width font in the *Windows 8* command-line (it should be similar on *Windows 7*).

### Installation:

I got the font from [here](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/Bitstream-Vera-Sans-Mono), the `Bitstream Vera Sans Mono Roman` version.

I installed it by clicking on the `.ttf` file and pressed *Install*.

Then I located it here:

[image: installed]

### Regedit:

Started `regedit` and located:

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\currentVersion\console\TrueTypeFont
```

The `0` and `00` names where already defined, so I added the `000` name, with the string value:

`Bitstream Vera Sans Mono`

[image: regedit]

First, I had an extra space in front of the font name, and that did not work.

After I restarted the computer, I visitied the command-line properties:

[image: cmd]

and found that the newly installed font was available.

Now the command line looks like this:

[image: cmd]

Hope this help.

### References:

This tutorial helped me along the way:

http://www.wikihow.com/Customize-the-Font-in-Windows-Command-Prompt